# Why S and T instead of A and B?

Tags: java, generics, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

This may be a silly question about generic types but I can't find any good explanation behind naming conventions followed in generic types.
If there is a class with two generic types; Java programmers usually define it like:

```
class Foo<S extends Abc,T extends Pqr>{
   S sVar;
   T tVar;
}
```

Why not something simple like :

```
class Foo<A extends Abc,B extends Pqr>{
   A aVar;
   B bVar;
}
```

I just want to ask why such naming conventions are followed? Is there any reason behind `S` and `T`? or are this conventions came from other languages (say c++ templates)?

Comment: One possibility is that `T` was an abbreviation for `Type`, and they chose `S` since it is the previous letter in the alphabet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

> #### Type Parameter Naming Conventions
>
> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> ```
> E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> K - Key
> N - Number
> T - Type
> V - Value
> S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
> ```
>
> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API and the rest of this lesson.

---

In particular note the: *"Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name."*, with which I certainly agree.

Most people would use `T` and `S` because that is common practice, and as such it will *readable* for most other people. But I would add that I see the names `A` and `B` also used as example names for classes: `class A {...}`, `class B {...}`. Using them as type variable names would make them hard to tell apart.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from OCP.Oracle.Certified.Professional.Java.SE.8.Programmer.II.Study.Guide.Exam.1Z0809""

**Naming Conventions for Generics**

A type parameter can be named anything you want. The convention is to use single
uppercase letters to make it obvious that they aren’t real class names. The following are common letters to use:

- E for an **e**lement
- K for a map **k**ey
- V for a map **v**alue
- N for a **n**umber
- T for a generic data **t**ype
- S, U, V, and so forth for multiple generic types

This is as far as the authors go with their argumentation behind the convention. I guess S, U & V are used because they are nearer with respect to alphabetical order to T (which stands for Type)